# Fedora16, ekiga just works in superuser mode

Tags: networking, fedora, non-root-user, sip

I've got a fedora16 running and I'd like to use ekiga as a softphone.

Now I'm running into some problems.

Starting ekiga as a normal user gives me

> could not register (globally not acceptable)

So I was pretty stuck.

Now I tried running ekiga with sudo and it worked.

So I asume, that it is a problem with the rights-management about the network settings.

I also have problems when I try running some server applications like apache and try to connect from a pc in the local network.

So it would be nice if someone could explain me, what to do, to get ekiga running as a normal user.

Comment: Fedora 16 is *long* end-of-life, no more updates. Upgrade.

Comment: You are probably behind a symmetric NAT (or just a firewall that blocks UDP 5060).

Comment: well, you know I had this problem 3 years ago. AFAIR Fedoras right-management was tricky. So in the mean time I switched between Arch, Ubuntu and Windows 8. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the regular user in some groups like audio, video, if it's not already present.